# Virtual fields with Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I need to have a virtual property in my user entity. I followed the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties).

**UserEntity.php**

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity {

    protected $_virtual = ['full_name'];

    protected function _getFullName() {
        return $this->_properties['firstname'] . ' ' . $this->_properties['lastname'];
    }
}
```

**In a controller**

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$user = $users->get(29);
$firstname = $user->firstname; // $firstname: "John"
$lastname = $user->lastname; // $lastname: "Doe"
$value = $user->full_name; // $value: null
```

I followed exactly the book and I only get a `null` value.

Comment: Are you sure the user object has data in it?

Comment: Yes. Just look at the line comments after  $user->firstname, $user->lastname;

Comment: Try `debug([get_class($users), get_class($user)])`, you may not operate on the obejcts that you expect...

Comment: @richerlariviere I wasn't sure if that was a copy and paste or you know the values contained.

Comment: @ndm: the output is [(int) 0 => 'App\Model\Table\UsersTable', (int) 1 => 'Cake\ORM\Entity']. I assume it's ok.

Comment: That means that the `User` entity class/file cannot be found... and on  a second look, the filename should be `User.php`, not `UserEntity.php`, it must match the classname.

Comment: @ndm even after using proper naming convention I'm getting null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to @ndm, the problem was due to a bad file naming. I named the user entity class `UserEntity.php`. [The CakePHP name conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) says that:

> The Entity class OptionValue would be found in a file named OptionValue.php.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity {

protected $_virtual = ['full_name'];

 protected function _getFullName() {
   return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname ;
 }
}
```

[you can back to resource here](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just go for something like this?

```
/*
 * Return Fullname
 */
public function getFullname()
{
    $name = $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
    return $name;
}
```