# CakePHP displayField with multiple parameter

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to combine two database rows (**first_name** and **last_name**) to use them as one displayField (**full_name**)

I heared about virtual Fields but was not able to use them in my project.

Here's my UsersTable.php

```
class UsersTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $virtualField = ['full_name' => 'CONCAT(User.first_name, ", ", User.last_name)'];

        $this->displayField('full_name');
    }
}
```

Instead of getting the full name I just get a blank page.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437227/virtual-fields-with-cakephp-3

Comment: easier than expected, thanks Ofir